# Cheerio error with each loop on class selector - TypeError: Cannot set property 'range' of undefined

Tags: json, node.js, request, cheerio

I have a simple Cheerio parse i'm doing on a request app.  Not sure why this undefined error is coming up when trying to set the array but i'm guessing the value isn't there for it to set.

```
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);

        var json = [  
            { "range": "", "address": "", "state": "", "zip": "", "info": "" }
        ];

        $('.findCourse').each(function (i, elem) {
            // Range Name
            console.log("iteration - ", i);
            console.log("name - ", $(this).text().trim());
            json[i].range = $(this).text().trim();
        });
```

Here is my console response with it reading and setting the first two items it finds in the scraped html.

```
iteration -  0
name -  Pollock's Ferry Hunting Club Inc.
iteration -  1
name -  Eagle 1
```

> > TypeError: Cannot set property 'range' of undefined
> >
> > ```
> > at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/node_app/server.js:30:31)
> >   at exports.each (/usr/local/node_app/node_modules/cheerio/lib/api/traversing.js:267:24)
> > at Request.request.post.form.__EVENTTARGET [as _callback] (/usr/local/node_app/server.js:26:30)
> > at Request.self.callback (/usr/local/node_app/node_modules/request/request.js:121:22)
> > at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
> > at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/node_app/node_modules/request/request.js:978:14)
> > at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
> > at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/node_app/node_modules/request/request.js:929:12)
> > at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
> > at _stream_readable.js:920:16 1 May 23:02:57 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
> > ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the issue.  The debugging statements were being executed before the reference error was thrown.

Simple javascript array issue where I was trying push the new element into the array at a position that didn't exist.

Here is my fix.

```
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    var json = [];

    $('.findCourse').each(function (i, elem) {
        // Range Name
        json.push({});
        json[i].range = $(this).text().trim();
    });
```